# How to get React to parse new lines from components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I get React to parse new lines given by a component?

Something like `<ComponentWhichReturnsText />` in a `return` in a functional component seemingly ignores if that component has `\n` in it.

Minimal reproducible example:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/cool-worker-wleqx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Expected result:

```
Text line 1
Text line 2
```

Actual result:

```
Text line 1 Text line 2
```

Also, when giving your answers, please keep the same structure. The text I have must come from a component and that component must be directly rendered in my `App`'s `return`. Something which can be modified is the text (so for example inserting characters to get the new lines to parse).

Comment: how about:
export default function Component() {
  return (<><p>Text line </p> <p>Text line 2</p></>);
}

Comment: You can also use "<br />". <div>Text line 1 <br />Text line 2</div>